# Accessing the registry key having Quotation Mark

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-xe2

I want to open a registry key in the format XXX'XX from Delphi XE2

```
Rootpath := '\SOFTWARE\XXXX XXXX\XXXXX''XXX\XXX';
Reg.OpenKey(Rootpath, FALSE);
```

Since Delphi escape character for ' is '' I cannot able to open the registry.

Looking for your help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it was a mistake in the question corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping the single quote with `''` in a string works perfectly well. The resulting string contains a single character. That's the whole point of escaping it. To convince yourself of this try writing such a string to the console, or showing it in a message box.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
begin
  Writeln('XXX''XXX');
end.
```

This program outputs:

```
XXX'XXX
```

The reality is that your problem is elsewhere. Possible reasons include:

- You got the path wrong, or
- you did not account for registry redirection, or
- your user does not have sufficient privileges to open the key with the rights you requested.

Comment: Yes , it is the privilege. Thank you.